Navigate to home page from its dynamic page
I have below code where i got all details in my dynamic page. when I hit nav back its taking me all the way back to app home screen, looking for solution to go to initial page withoutout dynamic page details.Will page refresh will work? how to get page fresh option in ui5
Code

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't show code as images, instead, paste the code directly into your question and use backticks ` to distinguish it.

It's hard to decide without the full code, but basically, if your home page route differs from your detail page root you can get back to the home page using routing:
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("home_route_name");

